# rdbuf() strange behavior

Tags: c++, string, file, buffer

I'm trying to merge two files into one by simply using rdbuf(), but when merged, the file's first line is missing. The code is below:

```
void mergeFiles(ifstream &file1, ifstream &file2, ofstream &file3) {

    int num1;
    int num2;

    string firstLine_1;
    string firstLine_2;

    getline(file1, firstLine_1);
    num1 = atoi(firstLine_1.c_str());

    getline(file2, firstLine_2);
    num2 = atoi(firstLine_2.c_str());

    if (num1<num2) {
        file3 << file1.rdbuf() << "\n" << file2.rdbuf();
    } else {
        file3 << file2.rdbuf() << "\n" << file1.rdbuf();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `atoi`, you should definitely just use `num1 << file1;`, as this will be much more robust.

Comment: `atoi` makes my eyes bleed.  Try `stoi` (if exceptions for errors are good) or else `strtoi` (if you like checking return values instead of catching exceptions)  Or, you can keep using `atoi`, if you want failures to possibly crash your program!

Comment: @MarcusMüller: You got left and right operands (and direction of the angle brackets) reversed, perhaps?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Um, this did *definitely* only happen because I'm tired. Going to bed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you pull out the first line of each file before concatenating the rest of them, so that's expected. You still have the lines, though, so simply print them in between:

```
if (num1<num2) {
    file3 << firstLine_1   << "\n"
          << file1.rdbuf() << "\n"
          << firstLine_2   << "\n"
          << file2.rdbuf();
} else {
    file3 << firstLine_2   << "\n"
          << file2.rdbuf() << "\n"
          << firstLine_1   << "\n"
          << file1.rdbuf();
}
```

**Addendum:** @BenVoigt rightly notes that if one of the files contains a single line that does not end with a newline, the output of this will be different from printing the plain file contents delimited by a single newline (there will be an extra newline in the middle or at the end).

On the basis that this case is recognizable because the first `getline` call will have set the end-of-file flag, this can be avoided as follows:

```
if (num1<num2) {
    file3 << firstLine_1;
    if(file1) { file3 << "\n" << file1.rdbuf(); }
    file3 << "\n";
    file3 << firstLine_2;
    if(file2) { file3 << "\n" << file2.rdbuf(); }
} else {
    file3 << firstLine_2;
    if(file2) { file3 << "\n" << file2.rdbuf(); }
    file3 << "\n";
    file3 << firstLine_1;
    if(file1) { file3 << "\n" << file1.rdbuf(); }
}
```

Since this is something of a mouthful and repetitive, I'd consider using a lambda to make it more concise:

```
auto printfile = [&file3](std::string const &firstline, std::istream &in) {
  file3 << firstline;
  if(in) { file3 << "\n" << in.rdbuf(); }
};

if(num1 < num2) {
  printfile(firstLine_1, file1);
  file3 << "\n";
  printfile(firstLine_2, file2);
} else {
  printfile(firstLine_2, file2);
  file3 << "\n";
  printfile(firstLine_1, file1);
}
```

For regular files like these, seeking back is also a possibility, but I feel that it is better to avoid giving up the ability to use code on pipes, sockets and other non-seekable streams without a compelling reason even if it seems like an unlikely use case.

Comment: Also a good solution.  Although it might add more newlines than were in the original file, that might be a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
file3 << filen.rdbuf()
```

Copies from the current position in the `filen` stream forward, into `file3`.  The current position is after the first line, since you just read it.

Seek back to the beginning and your missing line will be missing no longer.